# angular-auth-oidc-client keycloak does not work

Tags: angular, authentication, keycloak, angular-auth-oidc-client

I am using docker-compose with angular app and keycloak auth server.
I have pulled a new image from keycloak today, all my angular application have crashed.

Here is my message when debugging angular-auth-oidc-client

```
[DEBUG] 0- - Getting signinkeys from  https://*****.com/auth/realms/****/protocol/openid-connect/certs
[DEBUG] 0- - Did not find any configured route for route https://*****.com/auth/realms/****/protocol/openid-connect/certs
[DEBUG] 0- - validate id token iat max offset -7315000 < 120000
[DEBUG] 0- - authCallback token(s) invalid
```

Angular error

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'unauthorized'
```

my angular-auth-oidc-client  settings

```
config: {
    secureRoutes: ['/'],
    authority: 'https://*****/auth/realms/*****',
    redirectUrl: window.location.origin,
    postLogoutRedirectUri: '*****',
    clientId: 'kn-pharmacy',
    scope: 'openid profile offline_access ', // 'openid profile offline_access ' + your scopes
    responseType: 'code',
    silentRenew: true,
    useRefreshToken: true,
    renewTimeBeforeTokenExpiresInSeconds: 30,
    logLevel: LogLevel.Debug,
    ignoreNonceAfterRefresh:true
  },
```

I have tried to redo my last commit for my angular project but that did not resolve the issue. and three other angular application which relay on the keycloak server have stopped working too.

Currently I am using
Angular@12.2.13,
angular-auth-oidc-client@12.0.3

keycloak is set to latest

Answer (score 2):

It looks like time/clock on your local machine and your docker container are out of sync.

```
[DEBUG] 0- - validate id token iat max offset -7315000 < 120000
```

I would read this like you allow an offset of 120 seconds, but actually the time is off by 7315 seconds.

Comment: thanks for the help :D